# Leaving the USA after 90days ESTA runs out

Tags: usa, canada, esta

Im (german citizen) currently staying in the US with the 90 days esta.

Is it sufficient to leave the US and stay in mexico or canada (I can stay there for 180 days) or do I have to leave north america altogether?

Comment: If you stay in Canada or Mexico for 180 days then you probably won't have trouble getting back into the US.

Comment: I don’t think this is an exact duplicate of the linked question because of the 180 days in Mexico or Canada.

Comment: If this question were reopened, I’d note the importance of making sure their I-94 card was returned or departure noted properly before trying to visit the USA again.

Comment: a) how long are you staying in the US with ESTA before leaving to Mexico/Canada, and b) after the 180 days in Mex/Can how long do you plan to stay? Do you have onward tickets?